# Multiply total orders to quantity of order in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, subtotal

I have a jquery that multiplies the price to quantity. Now I wanted to multiply the total of that to how many orders a costumer would place. Where would I insert my multiplication code? Here's how i envisioned the equation would be **total=(price*quantity)*numberoforders**. Here's a [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k91d23p6/2/) of what I cant eloquently explain

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" class="drink" value="DrinkName1" data-price="12" /> Sample Item
                <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
            </label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" class="drink" value="DrinkName2" data-price="6" /> Sample Item
                <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
            </label>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="drink[]" class="drink" value="DrinkName3" data-price="4" /> Sample Item
                <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" />
            </label>
        </li>

           <li>
            <label>
            Quantity of Orders
                <input min="0" max="5" type="number" class="totalquant" name="quantity" value="1" />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>


</form>

<p>Total</p>
<div id="totalDiv">0</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.quantity, .drink').change(calculateTotal);

function calculateTotal() {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form'), total = 0;
    $form.find('.drink:checked').each(function() {
        total += $(this).data('price') * parseInt($(this).next('.quantity').val() || 0, 10);
    });
    $('#totalDiv').text(total)* parseInt($(this).siblings('.totalquant').val() || 0, 10);
}
```

Appreciate all the help

Comment: where is the price for each item

Comment: @Wellwisher it's under data-price="" because im using the value for the name of the item

Comment: Your code is basically right. Just change the last line to `$('#totalDiv').text(total * parseInt($('.totalquant').val() || 0, 10));`. `.totalquant` isn't a direct sibling to any of the other inputs and you want to `$('#totalDiv').text()` by that value so move the parentheses outside. In short, make sure your selectors are right and you perform your math *before* assigning the text. [You can simplify your code a lot.](https://jsfiddle.net/ey29hx16/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some changes on your code here https://jsfiddle.net/k91d23p6/3/

Basically, you have to multiply the `total` by the `totalQuant` after the `forEach`.

```
//query the DOM once, instead of on every change
var $form = $('form'); //on a real app it would be better to have a class or ID
var $totalQuant = $('.totalquant', $form);
var totalDiv = $('#totalDiv');
$('.quantity, .drink, .totalquant', $form).change(calculateTotal);

function calculateTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $form.find('.drink:checked').each(function() {
    total += $(this).data('price') * parseInt($(this).next('.quantity').val() || 0, 10);
  });
  var totalQuant = total * parseInt( $totalQuant.val() || 0, 10);
  totalDiv.text(totalQuant);
}
```